# MSSQL Database of Golden Gate 2002 program of Turnstyle

Tags: c#

I want to make connection between database (called GGLite) of Golden Gate 2002 program and C# to retrive enter-exit time of employees. But I can't find enter-exit time table in MSSQL database. How can I do this?

Golden Gate 2002 program shows enter-exit time,but I want C# program to show enter-exit time.

Has anybody got idea?

Comment: Check the documentation that comes with the program.